# Automatic termination of PMI for adjustable rate mortgage (recast)

Tags: united-states, mortgage, pmi

We made a substantial principal reduction (~80% of original loan) as part of a recast on an adjustable rate mortgage.  I was unaware that I'd have to request PMI removal.  That does seem to be pretty clearly true *if* this was a fixed rate mortgage (what was said [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20993/pmi-cancellation-based-on-original-mortgage-amount#comment28620_21008)).  However, for adjustable rate mortgages, the law uses the wording "Amortization schedule then in effect" ([sections 4902.b.2, 4901.18.b, and 4901.6](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?hl=false&edition=2022&req=granuleid%3AUSC-1999-title12-chapter49&num=0&saved=%7CZ3JhbnVsZWlkOlVTQy0xOTk5LXRpdGxlMTItc2VjdGlvbjQ5MDI%3D%7C%7C%7C0%7Cfalse%7C1999)).  My understanding is a recast results in a new amortization schedule that should have clearly had me under 78% of original value and my interpretation of the law is PMI should have automatically terminated essentially immediately.  The mortgage servicer is just repeatedly telling me that I have to request cancellation and pay for appraisal.

Am I misreading the law?

Comment: It depends, read the fine print of your mortgage agreement, it might be something they have in there.